# How can I trigger an email+attachment from the browser?

Tags: firefox, email, firefox-addon, attachment

This is for a company intranet app, so everyone is using firefox on XP and I can install whatever is needed.

We'd like to setup an email with a pre-made subject and attachment (similar to using mailto), but the mailto spec doesn't allow attachments.

Any ideas how it can be done? Perhaps using a ff extension?

update: The file is a network file at the company.

update: A good deal of customisation happens in each users outlook, signatures etc. that we'd like to keep.

Comment: Is the attachment a local file or a file on the webpage?

Comment: If the mailto spec allows an attachment, wouldn't it be a big security risk for web site to steal arbitrary local file?

Comment: @Wai Yip Tung - Yea, which is why it isn't allowed. We'd still like to make this work though :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably much better off providing a form for the users to fill out and and doing the email from the web server.  That will give you the most flexibility.

Comment: A good deal of customisation happens in each users outlook, signatures etc. that we'd like to keep. So posting through the server isn't an option :(